# Asyncio: start and stop a TCP server while loop is running

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm creating a program to act as a proxy between a browser and a piece of hardware. The browser initiates the connection as a websocket.  The program then starts a TCP server using the port specified in the initial request. Once the external device makes a connection to the TCP server, it can send data to the browser.  The code example works up to this point, but I also need the program to shutdown the TCP server and all connections if any of the connections are closed. Another websocket request should start the process again.

I don't seem to be stopping the server/websocket correctly since the system will not allow anymore websocket connections from the browser (The connection is refused). However, all other handlers will still respond on the http server.

```
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

def TCPServerFactory(conns):
    def _f(*args,**kwargs):
        return TCPServer(conns,*args,**kwargs)
    return _f

async def sendWS(conn,data):
    await conn.send_str(data) 

class TCPServer(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self,conns,*args,**kwargs):
        self.conns=conns
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def connection_made(self,transport):
        self.transport=transport
        self.conns['tcp']=transport

    def data_received(self,data):
        asyncio.ensure_future(sendWS(self.conns['ws'],data.decode()))

    def connection_lost(self,exc):
        self.conns['ws'].close()

async def sendTCP(conn,data):
    await conn.write(data)

async def wsHandler(request):
    ws=web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    #Setup TCP server
    loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    conns={'ws':ws,'tcp':None}
    try:
        serv=await loop.create_server(TCPServerFactory(conns),'127.0.0.1',8000)
    except:
        await ws.close()
        return ws
    conns['tcpServ']=serv

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type==aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if msg.data:
                try:
                    conns['tcp'].write(bytes(msg.data,'utf-8'))
                except:
                    break
        elif msg.type==aiohttp.WSMsgType.CLOSING:
            break
        else:
            break
    try:
        conns['tcp'].close()
    except:
        pass
    serv.close()
    await serv.wait_closed()
    await ws.close()
    return ws

async def handleTCP(request):
    return web.Response(text='TCP worked',headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'})

async def handleHome(request):
    return web.FileResponse(r'c:\workspace\lserver\lserver\test.html')

class HttpServer:
    def start(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())
        self.loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.app=web.Application()
        self.app.router.add_get('/tcp',wsHandler)
        self.app.router.add_get('/',handleHome)
        web.run_app(self.app,host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
        self.loop.close()

http=HttpServer()
http.start()
```